# Placeholder image not resized in Backend in magento 2

Tags: image, magento2.2.2, placeholder

I have uploaded place holder images in backend, while I am trying to edit the **configurable product** in backend.  Under **configuration section** It **displays the place holder image** at larger size for each child products. It has **failed to resize the place holder image as thumbnail image.**

**1)In what size should i upload a place holder image**

Please provide me a solution .